# No content provider found for permission revoke android native extension

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4.5, air-native-extension

I developed an android native extension for a flex project and i have this problem.
My native extension calls an activity on android and then my flex applcation crashes but has no obvious error. I looked in my android phone log an i saw this error : "No content provider found for permission revoke"

```
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fede.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="org.adw.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
                <application>
                     <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.apperhand.device.android.AndroidSDKProvider"/>
                     <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.DEV_ID" android:value= "112455740"/>
                      <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.APP_ID" android:value= "212206131"/>
                     <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
                     <activity android:name="com.apperhand.device.android.EULAActivity " 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" /> 
             <activity android:name="ro.waystudios.startappextension.StartAppActivity" 
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
                </application>
            </manifest>

        ]]></manifestAdditions>
```

This is my android activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidSDKProvider.initSDK(this);
    }
```

This is my call function:

```
Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context.getActivity(), StartAppActivity.class);
            context.getActivity().startActivity( startActivityIntent );
```